# Query first slow gets faster after expanding indexes via SMSS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a strange issue here's what is happening:
We are using our software (.NET) to retrieve data from a SQL Server in that exact case invoice pdfs.

One day we receive exceptions that the command is getting timeouts (standard 30 seconds).

Query:

```
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode0 AS Int = 215513015;
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode1 AS Int = 2096539237;
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode2 AS Int = 157206106;
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode3 AS Int = 831525925;
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode4 AS Int = 47575387;
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode5 AS Int = 15520597;
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode6 AS Int = 1096358716;
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode7 AS Int = 40195184;
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode8 AS Int = 6919968;
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode9 AS Int = 18223598;
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode10 AS Int = 95208170;
DECLARE @BZObjMemberCode11 AS Int = 884181766;
DECLARE @bzObjType AS Int = 7;

SELECT * FROM ArchivPdf WHERE BZObjMemberCode IN (@BZObjMemberCode0,@BZObjMemberCode1,@BZObjMemberCode2,@BZObjMemberCode3,@BZObjMemberCode4,@BZObjMemberCode5,@BZObjMemberCode6,@BZObjMemberCode7,@BZObjMemberCode8,@BZObjMemberCode9,@BZObjMemberCode10,@BZObjMemberCode11) AND BzObjType = @bzObjType AND PDF IS NOT NULL
```

After analyzing, I added a non clustered index on the fields BZObjMemberCode and BzObjType which resulted in a much faster query time from beyond 30 seconds to > 1 seconds. We updated our main application to distribute this index.

Soon after another customer reports the same issue.
Here comes the strange part what I did was the following:

- executed the query directly in the SMSS
- let it run for about 1 minute
- stopped the query
- navigate to the table(ArchivPDF)
- expanded the indexes folder
- rerun the query
- get the same fast query time "> 1 second"

So I optimized the given query by switching from the parameterized in list to joins and added Options Recompile and still get the same phenomenon just expanding the indexes folder magically accelerates the query somehow.

Can anyone help me to shed light on this issues?

Comment: I can't think of how enumerating the indexes in SSMS might be correlated but I want to mention that index stats may have changed between executions. With the option recompile query hint, the plan is generated based on estimates from the current stats histograms. Also verify the slowness is not due to another reason (e.g. blocking).

Comment: I can't think of any lock or blocking. On my first debug case I used a SELECT COUNT(*) on this table and had no issues with slowness or being blocked from another query.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

The Where-Part "AND PDF IS NOT NULL" was the cause. "PDF" is a VarBinary field.
I have to move the null check back to out main application.